# How do I get a whole TD to be clickable when using a background in a sub div

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```
<td> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="doSomething();">
<div class="backgroundIcon"></div></a></td>
```

I'm trying to make the whole TD element clickable, but if I don't have any text between `<div class="backgroundIcon"></div>` the icon doesn't show up.

I could change it to be `<div class="backgroundIcon">TEXT</div>` and set my `backgoundIcon` class to have `font-size:0` but I feel there must be a cleaner solution?

Comment: To make the whole `td clickable, why not put the `onclick` on the `td`?

Comment: @cale_b: that's absolutely fine in HTML 5; it was problematic - but worked - in HTML 4.1

Comment: @Gribbler I can't see your css but the rule is the divs, tds, any element really takes the height of what's inside. if you have nothing, it will have no height. Set height when it's empty and you should be fine.

Comment: To add to @Jabberwocky comment: You could set a `min-height` and `min-width` on the `.backgroundIcon` element to help ensure it takes space.

Comment: `<td onclick="doSomething();">`

Comment: You might consider reviewing how to create an [mcve] by the way.  You'd be more likely to get actual answers, rather than comments.

Comment: I went with <td onclick and this works well, I also added style:"cursor:pointer" . Thank you all for your help